# What's the best way to match a string by its abbreviation

Tags: java

I have a list called frequency [ quarterly, monthly, weekly, etc. ]. By calling a java method I would like a statement such as frecuencia.equals("Monthly") to evaluate correctly using an abbreviation such as " M".

Comment: `contains()` is a partial match `equals()` is a complete match. Probably you can Map the `frequency` to the abbreviations you want.

Comment: Try `if (frequency.startsWith(abbreviation)) { /* do something */ }`

Answer (score 1):

Instead of holding the frequencies on a `List` you may have them on a `Map` with the key being the abbreviation.

Example:

```
Map<String,String> mapping = new HashMap<>();
mapping.put("Q","quarterly");
mapping.put("M","mensual");
mapping.put("W","weekly");

String input = "M"; //scan, parse, or  received somehow from something

String frequency = mapping.get(input);
```

Now `frequency` holds `mensual`

Answer (score 0):

For contains() method in List:

```
boolean contains(Object o)

Returns true if this list contains the specified element. More formally, returns true if and only if this list contains at least one element e such that (o==null ? e==null : o.equals(e)).
```

For equals() method in List:

```
boolean equals(Object o)

Compares the specified object with this list for equality. Returns true if and only if the specified object is also a list, both lists have the same size, and all corresponding pairs of elements in the two lists are equal. (Two elements e1 and e2 are equal if (e1==null ? e2==null : e1.equals(e2)).) In other words, two lists are defined to be equal if they contain the same elements in the same order. This definition ensures that the equals method works properly across different implementations of the List interface.
```

So contains returns a boolean if a List contains an element while equals compares two lists and returns a boolean if both lists match. More can be found [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html)